# Tkinter assign buttons to entries in dynamically created widgets

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

How can I access an Entry content with pressing the corresponding Button in dynamically created widgets?
Below is the best I come up with so far. Thank you for any help.

```
from Tkinter import *

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.mf = Frame(self.master)
        self.l = ["white", "red", "blue", "brown"]
        self.font = ("Arial", 30)
        self.c, self.r = 1, 0
        self.cc, self.rr = 0, 0
        self.bel = []

        for c in self.l:
            action = self.print_entry
            self.e = Entry(self.mf, bg=c, width=10, font=self.font)
            self.e.grid(row=self.r, column=self.c)

            self.b = Button(self.mf, bg=c, text=c, font=self.font)
            self.b.grid(row=self.rr, column=self.cc)
            self.b.config(command=action)
            self.bel.append((self.b, self.e))
            self.rr += 1
            self.r += 1

        self.mf.pack()

    def print_entry(self): # this function prints the content of the entry
        pass

def main():
    root = Tk()
    display = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a reference to the entry widget into the command, using lambda or functools.partial.  For example:

```
self.b.config(command= lambda entry=self.e: action(entry))
...
def print_entry(self, entry): 
    print("the entry is '%s'" % entry.get())
```

---

By the way, using `self.b` and `self.e` is pointless, since those variables will only ever hold references to the last button and last entry. You should either use a local variable, and/or append the values to a list.

Comment: That's great. Thank you.